# What is the difference between UI gamObject and UI component?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the menus, you get the option to create a new gameObject or a component, for instance, of a button. Both of them seem to have same properties.

I understand that components can be attached to other controls, and gameObjects are complete objects by themselves, but which should be used when and why?

A deep insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've added an example image.**

It gives the general explanation.

[image]

**Furthermore**:

A GameObject, is the term referring to any and all objects in Unity3D. In Unreal Engine, we call the objects "Actors or Pawns".

In order for a GameObject to be manipulated or have functionality, they must have "Components".

So, let's imagine that a GameObject is just a container that had the ability to accept "components" like: Transform location data, a UI Button, a audio effect, a particle effect, code which allows user interactions, etc.

***Note:*** When we add a Unity3D GameObject, all GameObjects will come with some sort of Transform component already attached. In some cases, for example when you add a UI Button GameObject, it will come with several components already attached. These pre-attached components are usually required to make that GameObject function, and Unity has made life easier for us Developers by pre-attaching them.

You could create an "Empty GameObject" which will come with just a Transform Component. From there you could create a customized object of any type. If you wanted to create your own version of a UI Button, then you could do this by creating your own components to handle the looks, interactions, and events.

**Now, if we relate this to a UI GameObject:**

A UI GameObject is the container which holds all of your UI Components.

So in my example image, I display a UI GameObject named "MenuScreenCanvas", the reason i named it such is because it contains components which define it as a Canvas Element.

Next, we see i am highlighting the child UI GameObject named "PlayButton". This PlayButton UI GameObject has attached to it several UI Components, including: a Canvas Renderer, an Image (which is the gray background of the button), and a Button Script (which handles the interaction between a player click/tap on the screen and the actual GameObject.

**Breaking down components a little more:**

A component can range from the light data of an environment, to the audio source and their interactive in-game cues, to the code enabling a UI element to trigger an event due to a user interaction.

**Button Example:**

When you add a button by using the uGUI GameObjects:

[image]

That new button GameObject will come with components already attached, which conveniently allow you to create them quickly and efficiently.

This is how a standard button GameObject will look in the hierarchy, and the components you see in the inspector come standard as of Unity 5.2.0f3:

[image]

**Video Link: Making a standard button from scratch (Just for learning and because we can...):**

https://youtu.be/v7RiUvOG5H4 (Not sure if that helps at all, but i hope so...).

Hope that helps. If you need more, feel free to ask :D

Comment: "*A deep insight would be helpful.*" Is this a **deep** insight?

Comment: Oops. I'll add to it. Thanks for the note @WaiHaLee

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts to make me understand. As I commented on user3071284's post, the button component is different with canvas and other gameObjects. For the canvas, it is just like another button gameObject. For others, it is only a script. And that is what solves my confusion.

Comment: Could you edit and add my comment to your answer so that other people having the exact same query get answered here?

Comment: Will do when I get back on my computer later

Comment: @AkashAggarwal, the button component are not different in a canvas and other gameObjects. They are all just a Button script component attached to a normal GameObject. The difference will be in perhaps the name of the object and the hierarchical structure of the components in the inspector. I'm going to edit my answer a little more to ensure you get this point. (although you may already understand)

Comment: @AkashAggarwal: i edited my answer a little more with a video in hopes of that helping a little more as well. If you still want me to add your comment then please let me know.

Comment: My point was when you add a button component to a canvas, all the other things get added as well, making it identical to a button gameObject. On the other hand, if you add a button component to any other gameObject like a quad, only the script gets added. I understand the difference, I just want this query to be helpful to others. I'll check the video once I'm home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90141/discussion-between-ejsd1989-and-akash-aggarwal).

Comment: I'm out today. Surely we shall when I'm home.

Answer (score 1):

> In the menus, you get the option to create a new gameObject or a
>   component, for instance, of a button. Both of them seem to have same
>   properties.

The GameObject menu is for creating a new object in the scene. The Component menu is for adding a component to the selected scene object. For example, if creating a Button, there's no difference in the Button component's properties when creating it from the GameObject menu or adding a Button component to an empty game object.

> which should be used when and why?

In general, creating a game object meets the needs of most common use cases. I generally only use the Component menu when adding a collider or a script I created.

In the case of Button, creating it from the GameObject menu also creates a Text game object as the child of the Button. If you were to add a Button component to an existing game object, it wouldn't add the child Text game object for you. To have text on the Button, you'd have to create this child Text object yourself.

Comment: You probably didn't get my question right. My question is what is the difference between a **UI** gameObject and a **UI** component, when everything they contain are the same?

Comment: Also I want to know how to decide what is more suitable to create in any situation, not how to create one of these.

Comment: Nope, the button still has the text child element by default even if we create it as a component.
I guess the answer to my question would be that gameObjects can standalone, components don't.

Comment: @user3071284 your definition is clear in my opinion. Wondering if there is a confusion based on the architectural aspects of GameObjects vs Component? The previous comment "gameObjects can standalone, components don't", makes it seem like it more or less a question about how the individual UI elements exist in game. But i may be wrong :P

Comment: @ejsd1989 I understand the difference between a basic component and a basic gameObject. Its just that since unity gives an option to add a button as a component or a gameObject, I was confused all this while because I was adding them both to a canvas, and they were identical. Just recently, I added the button to a Quad and voila! Only the Button(script) component appeared. This is the difference I was looking for. user3071284 I forgot to say this before, thanks for your time and effort to sort my query.